# Java: creating objects based on string using class.forname.newinstance vs if statements

Tags: java

I came upon `class.forname.newInstance` while searching creating objects by `String`.
I know using the former method takes longer time than using keyword `new`, but how much longer? If I want to create an instance of the 100 classes I have based on the value of a `String`, how much longer would it take? Run time wise is it better to do just 100 if statements(I don't mind doing that, really..)?

Comment: Do all thoses classes have a supertype in common ?

Comment: Yes they all have the same constructor and extend the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using new operator is very fast and optimized because it performs compile time construction.

Class.forName().newInstance() performs dynamic construction which is much slower than new operator because type of object is not readily known during run time and certain Java virtual machine optimizations can not be performed.

Also reflection has security restrictions as they always require run time permission when running under security manager I highly dont recommend to use reflection unless you have specific reason to do that .

To answer your exact question , If you prefer  Class.forName().newInstance()  will cost you 4 times more (Atleast in my system when i tested the code for 100 operations) than the new operator.

[Avoid using reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 100 possible subclasses, writing 100 `if` seems very verbose and error-prone.

As arunprakashpj said, I wouldn't use reflection for the same reasons, however I wouldn't use 100 `if` neither. Instead I'll do the following to reduce a bit the verbosity but still by using the `new` operator:

```
Map<String, Supplier<YourBaseClass>> constructors = new HashMap<>();
constructors.put("Impl1", Impl1::new);
constructors.put("Impl2", Impl2::new);
...
```

Then you can construct an `ImplXXX` like that (no ifs required):

```
private static YourBaseClass construct(String classname) {
    return constructors.getOrDefault(classname, DummyImpl::new).get();
}
```